# Selection Menu lags while the file is loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, highcharts

I have a javascript selection menu which upon selection loads a large csv file and eventually populates a highchart graph.

When I click on a selection the dropdown menu essentially freezes while the file is loading.

Is there a way to allow the selection menu to finish its animation before the file is finished loading?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: asking questions like this without showing the code that controls this behavior is useless

Answer (score 0):

I apologize for not displaying the code.

I was able to get an easy solution...

I just added a .selectmenu( "close" ) within the function that is called when the menu is selected. Typically, the menu would close automatically but since the request is long, this forces is.